# getting intel-rapl: package locked by BIOS when i run dmesg. Is this normal?

Tags: 16.04, dmesg

> [   13.537375] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
>
> [   13.537377] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
>
> [   13.537382] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
>
> [   48.574128] powercap intel-rapl:0: package locked by BIOS, monitoring only

Comment: It has always been that way on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand only a BIOS update can unlock it. Some manufacturers decided that the BIOS should be where this is controlled and not the OS and they don't allow the OS to control it (same with me).